# Touch DragDrop in wpf

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, touch

I have a Touch Screen enabled application and i want to do some drag-drop using the touch events instead of mouse events. The problem is that DragDrop.DoDragDrop returns DragDropEffects.None when I trigger the drag-drop action from a touch event (touch down and touchmove combination).

With the mouse events everything works as expected.

I have no exception raised, and using the Surface toolkit is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as one of the other peoples that had the same problem, i solved it myself with a workaround.

On short, this is:
1.I had to add a handler for QueryContinueDragHandler in DragDrop. While the monitored touch is active the operation is Continue, otherwise Drop
2.On a preview touch move set on a toplevel container I had to mimic the cursor movement using some pinvoke (SetCursorPos in Win32 API)

I wish a better solution exists.